# How to replace component in ViewContainerRef in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am learning Angular and I need to create components dynamically and swap them in one container. I have a container:

```
<ng-container #container></ng-container>
```

And I need to do these steps:

1. To create a `firstComponent` and save reference to it (I can do it)
2. To create the `secondComponent` in the place of the first one. I remove the `firstComponent` and create the `secondComponent` (I can do it).
3. To remove the `secondComponent` and again insert the saved `firstComponent`. It is very important - not to create a new instance of the `firstComponent`, but insert the saved one. And this is what I can't do.

This the code I use to create components dynamically (angular 13):

```
@ViewChild("container", { static: true, read: ViewContainerRef })
container!: ViewContainerRef;

...
const firstComponent = this.container.createComponent<FirstComponent>(FirstComponent);
...
//to remove it I do
this.container.remove(0);
```

Could anyone say how to do step #3?

Comment: What does  happen when you do that? I mean what is the problem with your code?

Comment: @Novy I don't have any problems with step #1 and #2. I just don't know how to do step #3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `detach()` and `insert()` methods for such purpose.
According to the [documentation:](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#detach)

> Detaches a view from this container without destroying it. Use along with insert() to move a view within the current container.

```js
const firstComponent = this.container.createComponent<FirstComponent>(FirstComponent);

// detach without destroying
this.container.detach(0);

// insert the firstComponent with preserved elements.
this.container.insert(firstComponent.hostView, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like this

```
if(this.container && this.container.length>0){
    // if you do not know the index, search it first and than detach it
    this.container.detach(this.container.indexOf(firstComponent));
}
```